# Properties in a response object after a webservice call are null

Tags: c#, web-services

I can see the object in Fiddler but the object is not deserializing on my end. Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: I have the same problem and am currently pulling my hair out (especially as there seems to be no way of debugging the M$ C# code that deserializes the WS).

Answer (score 4):

"Response is null" or "Response contains nulls" or "Request is null" or "Request contains null" almost always mean that you have a namespace mismatch. For instance, the response may contain:

```
<response xmlns="http://foo.com"/>
```

but should in fact be

```
<response xmlns="http://bar.com"/>
```

In this case, null will be received.

Comment: How can I know what the namespace *should* be?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and as suggested the namespace problem was the root cause.However, my proxy class has nested classes and long chain of nested namespace.

It was confusing to identify the correct namespace to apply in Cs code for proxy class.  Here, i describe how to figure out the namespace which is required to be updated in client proxy.

What i did was intercept the request in ClientMessageInspector class, AfterReceiveReply method (Enables inspection or modification of a message after a reply message is received but prior to passing it back to the client application.) Verified the namespace of the object which were returning null in Response by using XMLDocument. I updated the proxy class with the namespace retreived from XML. After making the changes, the objects were not null in response.

```
 public class MyMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, object correlationState)
    {

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms);
        request.WriteMessage(writer); 

        writer.Flush();
        ms.Position = 0;
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(ms);
        this.ReadMessage(xmlDoc);


        ms = new MemoryStream();
        xmlDoc.Save(ms);
        ms.Position = 0;
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(ms);
        Message newMessage = Message.CreateMessage(reader, int.MaxValue, request.Version);
        newMessage.Properties.CopyProperties(request.Properties);
        request = newMessage;

    }

    private void ReadMessage(XmlDocument xmlDoc)
    {
        XmlNode v1 = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("XPAth");
        //Actual Namespace in XML, which should be used in Proxy Class
        string namespaceURIForObjectInXML = v1.NamespaceURI;
    }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel)
    {

    }



}
```

Comment: Thank you Abhinav, It has resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar case where I created a client via SVCUTIL / Service Reference from VS. The response was received successfully with correct data (confirmed via IClientMessageInspector.AfterReceiveReply method) however the values at the object level were not being populated. There were no de-serialization errors (confirmed via system.diagnostics output)

The problem was twofold:

1) Certain objects were named exactly as their types but had different namespaces from their types. This seems to have confused the proxy generator in assigning the namespace parameter (in the System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute annotation) of the class to the one of the object

2) The order parameter (in the System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute annotation) of the properties was not required and also the namespace parameter was missing

so from: [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true, Order=0)]

to: [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true, Namespace="http://www.whathevernamespaceiscorrect.com")]

So basically, in the generated proxy I needed to fix the namespace of the class to the one specified in the type, and replace the order parameter with the namespace parameter setting it to the correct namespace according to the wsdl

Comment: You give me the clue. The namespace is not correct in the child's properties. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can think of is a contract mismatch. Although it's strange if no validation error is thrown. Are you using a client generated from the correct WSDL? Is it a WCF client or a SOAP one? The former one does validation, I'm sure, but schema mismatches may slip through the latter.

Comment: This occurs when generating the proxy class from the wsdl tool and when adding it as a service reference through the VS2010 GUI. This is a SOAP client.

Comment: Use svcutil.exe, not wsdl.exe. Or just use "Add Service Reference" and point to the WSDL or metadata endpoint.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem as this - the namespaces I see in the WSDL and XML response (in Fiddler) are exactly the same.  Also using a SOAP client.The response object is a simple wrapper around a generic array (from the (Java) serverside which is annotated with @XmlElementRefs({@XmlElementRef(type = Class1.class, ... }) the XML passed to the C# client looks fine as: <reponse xmlns="..."><return><class1>...</class1><class1>...</class1>....</response>.  C# creates the response object but fails to populate the array...

Answer (score 0):

Every time this happens to me, it's because I need to update my service references.  Try that and let me know what happens :)

Comment: thanks for response but trust me, I've deleted and recreated about a thousand times =(
However it's quite possible I'm missing something equally simple or am making a stupid mistake somewhere else (my first C# app)
I've tried with VS 2010 and SharpDevelop, all to no avail...

Comment: Ok, I would appreciate it since you asked the question if you could do it one more time though please.  I.e. update the service reference, rather than delete and recreate.  Assuming that doesn't work, it would be ideal to see the definition/contract for the object(s) and method involved :)

Comment: I've refreshed in SharpDevelop and it was all the same as before.  When I refreshed the WebService Reference in VS Express 2010 it changed the C# namespace prefixing the project's default namespace to the service reference (like DefaultNamespace.ServiceReference).  Executing from either IDE results in the same response object with null fields.

Comment: Could you post the definition of any types/methods involved as requested then please?:)

Comment: please see below (apologies for slight delay; i spent a while trying to cram the code snippets into a comment)

Comment: awarding you bounty for willingness to help  =)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it... or at least have workaround.  In the Java code the @XmlElementRefs and @XmlElementRef should have been @XmlElements and @XmlElement respectively (as well as the "type" attribute it needed a "name" attribute).

Guessing if I'd posted this as a new question with a Java tag as well as C# and web-services some hawk-eyed stackoverflower would have spotted this schoolboy error.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue which i resolved by checking the Order value in the Reference.cs.
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]

The order of the return parameters had changed but updating my service reference in visual studio didn't change the "Order" value.

Check that parameters returned in Fiddler/SoapUI are the same as in your proxy generated class.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the definition / specification matches the output. Compare the WSDL (in browser) and the response (in SOAP-UI, Fiddler), e.g.

- WSDL uses camel case (lastName) and
- response uses underscores (last_name).